# How to display ProgressBar inside a Switch?

Tags: android, material-design

I have a use-case where I need to display the processing state with a `Switch`. As per the material design, I should display `Switch` such as [image: this].

I tried overlapping `ProgressBar` over `Switch` but didn't work out as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: I wrapped `ProgressBar` and `Switch` with `FrameLayout`, but the end result was not very convincing so I reverted that stuff : (

Comment: A constraintlayout or even a relativelayout for something like this should work ok. Overlap, position and size the elements correctly and you should get your result.

Answer (score 2):

You can try combining Progress Bar with Switch in Constrant layout like this:

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switchCompat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switchCompat"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/switchCompat"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/switchCompat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/switchCompat" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

if that doesn't work then you need to create your own switch or use switch library with progressbar included.

Comment: Sorry dude this is not working. The progress bar should move along with the switch thumb.

Comment: @iCantC Is above code is working fine in your layout (without moving thumb)?